# What does __bridge mean in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

I am following a tutorial in Core Graphics and I came across the code __bridge. I looked into it and saw that it had to do with ARC but I am confused on what it does. Could someone explain what it does in this context?

```
    void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef endColor)
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    NSArray *colors = @[(__bridge id) startColor, (__bridge id) endColor];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

}
```

Comment: It transfers ownership. And I hope there's more to that method or you have at least two leaks.

Comment: I suggest to read "Managing Toll-Free Bridging" in the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) !

Comment: @Kevin Not to split hairs, but `__bridge` explicitly does not transfer "ownership". As [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1) says "`__bridge` transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).  From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> `__bridge` transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.